# Property does not exist on type 'unknown' error for no visible reason

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I am working on an Angular application and want to retrieve data from a Rest API. I have a service that retrieves the data and a component where I want to display the data. The service works fine; however, for no understandable reason, I get the following errors when compiling my application:

```
Error: files/files.component.html:43:36 - error TS2339: Property 'platform' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

43                         <td>{{list.platform}}</td>
                                      ~~~~~~~~

  files/files.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: 'files.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FilesComponent.


Error: files/files.component.html:44:36 - error TS2339: Property 'keyword' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

44                         <td>{{list.keyword}}</td>
                                      ~~~~~~~

  files/files.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: 'files.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FilesComponent.


Error: files/files.component.html:45:36 - error TS2339: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

45                         <td>{{list.username}}</td>
                                      ~~~~~~~~

  files/files.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: 'files.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FilesComponent.


Error: files/files.component.html:46:36 - error TS2339: Property 'createdAt' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

46                         <td>{{list.createdAt}}</td>
                                      ~~~~~~~~~

  files/files.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: 'files.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FilesComponent.


Error: files/files.component.html:47:114 - error TS2339: Property '_id' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

47                         <td><button class="btn  btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template, list)" data-id="{{list._id}}">Show</button></td>
                                                                                                                    ~~~

  files/files.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: 'files.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FilesComponent.




✖ Failed to compile.
```

List is unkknown and I cannot understand why; hence, any help or hints would be appreciated.
This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FileService, PaymentService } from '../services';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { FormBuilder, UntypedFormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'files.component.html'
})
export class FilesComponent implements OnInit{
  public data: any = [];
  modalRef?: BsModalRef;
  paymentForm: UntypedFormGroup;

  public list
  constructor(
    private fileService: FileService,
    private paymentService: PaymentService,
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.data = []
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fileService.fileList()
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      (list) => {
        this.data = list;
        //console.log('logging list',list);
        this.data.forEach((e1,i) => {
          e1.index = i;
          //console.log(e1.bytecode)
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        if (error.error.error?.verifyUser) {
        } else {
          // this.snackBService.openSnackBar(
          //   `Incorrect Username or Password !!!`,
          //   false
          // );
        }
      }
    );
  }

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>, list:any) {
    console.log(list);
    this.list = list; // Dynamic Data
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }

  callNextPage(template: TemplateRef<any>, list:any) {
    console.log(list);
    console.log('Next page called');
    this.list = list; // Dynamic Data
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }

  deny(template: TemplateRef<any>,index){
    console.log('called');
    this.modalRef.hide();
    if(this.data[index+1]){
      this.list = this.data[index+1]; // Dynamic Data
      this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
    }
  }
  

  payment() {
    this.paymentService
      .getPaymentLink()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        (links: any) => {
          if (links) {
            let paymentLink = links.links.find(x => x.rel === 'approve');
            // this.router.navigate([paymentLink]);
            window.location.href = paymentLink.href
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          if (error.error.error?.verifyUser) {
            // this.openDialog(error.error.error?.user);
          } else {
            // this.snackBService.openSnackBar(
            //   `Incorrect Username or Password !!!`,
            //   false
            // );
          }
        }
      );
  }
}
```

This is my template:

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> Image List
        </div>
        <ng-template #template>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>{{list.platform}}</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef?.hide()">
              <span aria-hidden="true" class="visually-hidden">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <p>{{list.keyword}}</p>
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <img style="border:1px solid gray;max-width:450px; max-height: 350px;"
                    src="data:image/png;base64,{{list.bytecode}}" />
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 2%;">
                    <!-- <form [formGroup]="paymentForm" > -->
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" (click)="payment()">Accept</button>
                    <!-- </form> -->
                    <button class="btn  btn-danger" (click)="deny(template,list.index)">Deny</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>

        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Platform</th>
                        <th>Keyword</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Datetime</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let list of data | slice:0:30; let i=index">
                        <td>{{list.platform}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.keyword}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.username}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.createdAt}}</td>
                        <td><button class="btn  btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template, list)" data-id="{{list._id}}">Show</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Prev</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" onclick="callnextPage()" href="#">2</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" onclick="callnextPage()" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" onclick="callnextPage()" href="#">4</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" onclick="callnextPage()" href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FileService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fileList() {
    return this.http.get(
      `https://api.xxx/files`
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried define and initialize list as follows:

```
public list: unknown = [];

declare global list;
```

it didn´t solved the error.

I am stuck with this and I don´t know how to solve this error, hence I would appreciate any hints or help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you get this error messages, because your `list` class member has no type, resp. unknown. How would Angular (Typescript) know, that there should be a `platform`, a `keyword`, etc. properties.

To solve this, define an interface (preferably in a separate file) like this:

```
export interface ApiResponse {
   platform: string,
   keyword: string,
   [...other properties]
}
```

And assign this interface as type to the `list` class member:

```
public list: ApiResponse[] = []
```

And in the subscribe, assign the api response to it:

```
this.list = list;
```

Now, you should have access to this properties in the template.